# Downloading File in C# with DownloadUrl

Tags: c#, xamarin, download

I have the downloadurl property from a DriveItem and now want to use this url to download the file in my App. When I open the url in a browser the download starts automatically.

I tried to find an elegant way of downloading the file in the app without having to open a browser.
However, when I try 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mydownloadurl");`
I get back the Error `Exception: Cannot find the specified file`

The only way I manged it to work was with
`await Browser.OpenAsync(mydownloadurl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);`

However, I would like the process to happen in the background without the user having to exit the browser and manually switching back to my app. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try [using this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=netstandard-2.1).

Comment: `WebClient` is your friend.